# Use web-based database administration software hosted on an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgresql, database

My question is the following: is there any way to host PostgreSQL pgAdmin4 on an AWS EC2 instance, and access the GUI remotely? I found this page here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html

It mentions briefly in the bottom section:

> ... from the device or Amazon EC2 instance where the application is running.

Which seems to indicate that this is possible, but I have not found any more information.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but you're probably better off using your local machine, over a VPN or tunnel if necessary.

Comment: The problem is I wish to deploy it for my entire team.

Comment: That's even more reason to implement a good remote access setup they can all use.

Comment: So the way to go is SSH Tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the advice from the comments, I decided to instead use either a VPN or tunnel.